# How does a XAML definition get turned into an object instance?

Tags: wpf, xaml

XAML allows you to specify an attribute value using a string that contains curly braces. Here is an example that creates a *Binding* instance and assigns it to the *Text* property of the *TextBox* element.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=Bar}"/>
```

I want to extend XAML so that the developer could enter this as valid...

```
<TextBox Text="{MyCustomObject Field1=Foo, Field2=Bar}"/>
```

This would create an instance of my class and set the Field1/Field2 properties as appropriate. Is this possible? If so how do you do it?

If this is possible I have a followup question. Can I take a string *"{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=Bar}"* and ask the framework to process it and return the *Binding* instance it specified? This must be done somewhere already to make the above XAML work and so there must be a way to ask for the same thing to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at markupextensions
http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/03/22/blogpost-text-creatingasimplecustommarkupextension.aspx

Comment: -1 I know this is old, but this is not the right way to go about it. Rather than creating you own markup extension, in this case you should be instantiating `MyCustomObject` in the Resources section of the XAML, and using normal binding to get to it.

Comment: link is dead and gone

Answer (score 2):

The `Binding` class is a [Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx).  You can write your own by deriving from `System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension`.

`ElementName` and `Path` are simply properties on the `Binding` object.

As for the followup you can create a new `Binding` in code by instantiating the `Binding` object.  I do not know of a way to process a string through.